# UIView drawRect; class variables out of scope

Tags: cocoa, uiview

Short & sweet version of my last question in light of new information.

I have a UIVIew with an init and a drawrect method (and another thread and a bunch of other stuff, but I'll keep it short & sweet).

All of the class variables that I alloc and init in the -(id)init method are out of scope/nil/0x0 in the drawRect method, and I am unable to access them.

For example;

In the interface:

```
NSObject* fred;
```

In the implementation:

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self == [super init])
    {
        fred = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"Fred is retained %i times",[fred retainCount]); //FAIL
    NSLog(@"But his variable is actually just pointing at uninitialised 0x0, so you're not reading this in the debugger because the application has crashed before it got here."
}
```

Should add that init IS being called before drawRect also. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*IS* it? Have you actually put a call to `NSLog` in there and *checked*? Because I would think it's initialized with `initWithFrame:` or something to that effect.

**Edit:** Some brief testing reveals that the issue isn't that fred is uninitialized; if it was; you'd not get any error, as sending messages to `nil` will not cause a crash. (Instance variables are initialized to `nil`). What is happening, in fact, is that somewhere along the line `fred` is released; causing the pointer to point to garbage, rather than an object. (Or rather, a garbled or garbaged object that can no longer receive messages.)

The code you have provided is not enough to find the error; you're going to have to paste more (and the exact code used in your application, too).

Comment: Unless he's calling init explicitly, which is conceivable.  But initialising the variable isn't related to scope issues - scope implies that the variable isn't declared correctly.

Comment: He's confusing scope with object lifetime. Cocoa objects don't die from leaving scope. And calling `init` explicitly on an `UIView`/`NSView` subclass, is, how you say, a Bad Idea™. If fred is nil, it was never initialized; if it was created and died; fred would point at garbage.

Comment: I used breakpoints to confirm execution of init, and that it is before drawRect.