# Property not set in drawRect method - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, drawrect, quartz-core

I have been seeing some strange behavior when I try to access a class variable or a property in my drawRect method..

In my .h file I have the following

```
@interface DartBoard : UIView
{
    Board * board;
    int index;
}
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) NSNumber * selectedIndex;
@end
```

In my .m file I have the following

```
@implementation DartBoard

@synthesize selectedIndex;

-(id)init
{
    self.selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
    index = 123;
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"selectedIndex: %d",[self.selectedIndex intValue]);
    NSLog(@"index: %d",index);
}

@end
```

the output is

```
2012-06-12 19:48:42.579 App [3690:707] selectedIndex: 0
2012-06-12 19:48:42.580 App [3690:707] index: 0
```

I have been trying to find a solution but have had no luck..

I found a similar question but there was no real answer to the issue

See: [UIView drawRect; class variables out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712502/uiview-drawrect-class-variables-out-of-scope)

I have a feeling drawRect is different that normal methods and is not getting the scope of the class correctly but how do I fix it?

Cheers
Damien

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a feeling drawRect is different that normal methods and is not getting the scope of the class correctly

No, there is nothing special about `-drawRect:`.

There are two possibilities:

**1. Your `-init` method is not being called.**

You didn't say how this view gets created -- if you are manually calling `[[DartBoard alloc] init]`, or if it is getting unarchived from a nib file.

If it's coming from a nib, `UIView`'s unarchiving doesn't know that your `init` method should be called. It will call the [designated initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Initialization.html) instead, which is `-initWithFrame:`.

So, you should implement that method instead, and make sure to call super!

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
        index = 123;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**2. There might be *two* instances of your view:** one that you are manually `init`ing, and another one that comes from somewhere else, probably a nib.  The second instance is the one that is being drawn. Since its variables and properties are never set, they show up as zero (the default value).

You could add this line to both your `-init` and `-drawRect:` methods, to see what the value of `self` is.  (Or, check it using the debugger.)

```
NSLog(@"self is %p", self);
```

Comment: also NSNumber is assigned and not retained, and it possible that it has been autoreleased by the time of drawrect

Comment: Yes, that's another bug: your property should use `retain` or `copy`, not `assign`.  That mistake might cause a crash later, but it isn't the root cause of the problem you asked about.

Comment: Brilliant thanks a lot guys... The issue was I had 2 instances one in the nib and one in the code i removed the one in the nib and all is well.. Got to love stack overflow...